# Ruby on Rails - Slow loading and spending a massive amount of time in garbage collector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection, profiling

I've got a large Rails app and I'm looking to improve (dismal) performance.

Running with ruby-prof doesn't help me much, I get output similar to this (running in production mode on thin):

```
Thread ID: 9322800
Total: 1.607768
Sort by: self_time

 %self     total     self     wait    child    calls   name
 26.03      0.42     0.42     0.00     0.00     1657   Module#define_method 
  8.03      0.13     0.13     0.00     0.00      267   Set#initialize 
  4.41      0.07     0.07     0.00     0.00       44   PG::Result#values 
  4.28      0.07     0.07     0.00     0.00     1926   ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback#start 
  4.21      0.07     0.07     0.00     0.00    14835   Kernel#hash 
  4.13      0.08     0.07     0.00     0.01      469   Module#redefine_method 
  4.11      0.07     0.07     0.00     0.00       63  *<Class::ActiveRecord::Base>#with_scope 
  4.02      0.07     0.06     0.00     0.00      774   ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback#_compile_options 
  3.24      0.05     0.05     0.00     0.00       30   PG::Connection#async_exec 
  2.31      0.40     0.04     0.00     0.37     2130  *Module#class_eval 
  1.47      0.02     0.02     0.00     0.00        6   PG::Connection#unescape_bytea 
  1.03      0.05     0.02     0.00     0.03      390  *Array#select 

* indicates recursively called methods
```

I guessed that maybe it is spending a lot of time in the garbage collector so since I'm running on [REE](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) I decided to try using GC.enable_stats to get some more information. I added the following to my application controller:

```
around_filter :enable_gc_stats

private

def enable_gc_stats
  GC.enable_stats

  begin
    yield
  ensure
    GC.disable_stats
    GC.clear_stats
  end
end
```

On a relatively large page running on my machine here in production mode with REE and the thin webserver (ruby-prof disabled since it makes it a bit slower) I get:

```
Completed 200 OK in 1093ms (Views: 743.1ms | ActiveRecord: 139.2ms)

GC.collections: 11
GC.time: 666299 us 666.299 ms
GC.growth: 461 KB

GC.allocated_size: 152 MB
GC.num_allocations: 1,924,773
ObjectSpace.live_objects: 1,015,195
ObjectSpace.allocated_objects: 12,393,644
```

So for a page that took 1093 ms, it seems like almost 700ms was spend in the garbage collector. Has anybody had this kind of problem before? I realize you cannot help with my app in particular (it is quite big with a lot of gems and things) - but are there techniques or tools to get a better idea why so much garbage is being created?

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your rails log shows most of the time (75%) is spent in view code.

Your profile report shows three obvious hotspots: `Module#define_method` for self time, `Module#class_eval` for total time, and `Set#initialize`.

`define_method` and `class_eval` indicate there's likely a lot of dynamic code execution which seems excessive to me -- generally you want to generate that code early and reuse it instead of repeatadly re generating it. It almost certainly is part of the problem with your excessive object allocation issues. Producing a graph report instead of a flat report should help you find the parent methods which are falling into these expensive paths and that may give you a pointer to where you could optimize.

`Set#initialize` may be a real artifact of what your code needs to do, or it might be a sign that there's some significant `Set[...]` or `Set::new` set creation calls inline which could be done once and assigned to a constant or instance/class var for reuse.

ruby-prof is ok, but you might want to also try [perftools.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb) which is easy to hook up to rack rails with [rack-perftools_profiler](https://github.com/bhb/rack-perftools_profiler).  perftools has some enhanced visualization tools which can make it much easier to understand hot execution paths.

Since you're running REE and extensive object allocation (and hence garbage collection) is an issue, you could try [memprof](https://github.com/ice799/memprof) to get some insight into what and where all these allocations are coming from.

If you can't find a path to reducing the amount of objects being allocated, you could ease the GC burden at the expense of larger process memory size by [tuning the GC](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_garbage_collector_performance_tuning) to prealloc a heap large enough to hold a typical request's allocation demands. Unicorn offers a rack module for [out of band GC](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/OobGC.html).  You might be able to adapt this module's approach to work with thin and move all the GC time to between requests -- you'll still pay the cpu cost, but at least you won't delay your responses for garbage collection.

Comment: Also, on `Set` usage; be aware that it uses a `Hash` under the covers - and for small sets (10s-100s of entries, usually), an `Array` is faster to check

Comment: @Nevir [my benchmark](https://gist.github.com/4584296) shows arrays faster than sets only up to cardinality 2; at three elements, sets become faster. (This benchmark assumes probed keys are evenly distributed among the elements of the collection).

Comment: Woah, kk; time to strike that stale fact from my memory!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'm going to go ahead and mark your answer. I haven't really made any progress yet. I agree about the Module#define_method - however it is not my code doing this, it seems to be Paperclip - but I still have no idea what is going on. The pointers to the tools are very useful - thanks.